# Tomcat перестает работать в одно и тоже время каждый день

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

Есть сервер на `digitalocean`. Установлены на сервере Mysql , Apache Tomcat, jre + jdk. Больше сторонних програм не ставил. На Tomcat крутится один `application` (в папку webapps закидываю war file). Сервер тестовый, юзеров там 2-3.

Каждый день, примерно в 8 утра, пересатет работать (ошибка: не удается получить доступ к сайту). Приходится заходить на сервер и рестартовать Tomcat, после чего все снова работает как часы. В приложении никаких шедуллеров и прочего нету. Перечитал все логи в папке /tomcat/logs ниче не нашел. Кто может что подсказать?

Comment: а какое локальное время в датацентре на тот момент? если предположить что сервер находиться на восточном побережьи, а Вы в Европе (то есть, в часовом поясе +1 - +3), то это как раз там полночь. Может в тарифном плане указан ребут в полночь?

Comment: последний ребут был несколько недель назад. проверял уже, думал тоже, ребутится(

Comment: чудес не бывает. Либо кто то завершает томкат, либо он сам завершается, например, падая. Или просто зависает на какой-то блокирующей задаче. Когда следующий раз зависнет, посмотрите, есть ли он в процессах - `ps aux | grep tomcat` (или как там бинарник называется) и смотрите наличие.